# Persistent FTP connection with file wrapper in php

Tags: php, ftp

If I do something like that:

```
rename('ftp://user:password@example.com/pub/file1.txt','ftp://user:password@example.com/pub/fileA.txt');
rename('ftp://user:password@example.com/pub/file2.txt','ftp://user:password@example.com/pub/fileB.txt');
rename('ftp://user:password@example.com/pub/file3.txt','ftp://user:password@example.com/pub/fileC.txt');
rm('ftp://user:password@example.com/pub/fileA.txt');
rm('ftp://user:password@example.com/pub/fileB.txt');
rm('ftp://user:password@example.com/pub/fileC.txt');
```

will php keep ftp connection between different operations on the same server? In other words I wonder if in such case php creates separate connection or keeps it alive? And if it creates separate connections then how could force it to use one when I transfer files using file wrappers. I know I could use different methods instead of ftp wrapper but I want to know how this works with file wrappers.

Comment: Probably no. Try using [PHP FTP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php)

Comment: Problem is I don't want change whole code especially that current method allows me to easily switch between ftp or sftp (ssh2.sftp://). Changing this class will require a lot work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just been looking at it with Wireshark and the answer is definitely No. Tested with PHP/5.2.19-win32.

As Robik suggests use the PHP [FTP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) if you want connection persistence.

Comment: Thanks for checking but the main question is if it is possible to change that behaviour without need to resign from url-style protocols. So I'm leaving question open for now.

Comment: You could [write your own wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php) fairly easily to do this...